# Kendo HierarchicalDataSource issue binding to Kendo treeview

Tags: kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo `HierarchicalDataSource` object bound to a Kendo `treeview` widget.

The `HierarchicalDataSource` simply returns a one-level-deep json formatted object, but for some reason it won't render in the `treeview`. It just shows the top node "Dimensions", but renders no data when expanded.

Here is my plunk [treeview sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/dJ0nIHyO2iI29QQYfEMg?p=preview) , which contains `index.html` and `script.js` .

FYI for script.js :
`$scope.dimenDataSource` is the Kendo HierarchicalDataSource object which uses the `transport` property to call my method `getDimensionsFromServer2` and also specify the `schema`.

Another FYI: In `getDimensionsFromServer2()` I have two ways of returning my test data. The `dataFlat` var returns a flat array, which renders fine. The `data` object has nested data, but does NOT render in treeview.

I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Thank you,
Bob

**** **UPDATE** ****

The problem was the incorrect placement of the `schema` setting (see my answer):

```js
settings.dimenDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {                
    read: function(options){
      datacontext.getDimensionsFromServer().then(function (data) {
        var rootnode = [{ name: "Dimensions", items: data.data }];
        options.success(rootnode);
      });
    },
    schema: {
       model: { children: "items" }
    },
    loadOnDemand: false                
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in the `schema` placement, which I had inadvertently placed in the `transport` option. It should placed at the same level, not within it.

Here's is the corrected version:

```js
settings.dimenDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {                
    read: function(options){
      datacontext.getDimensionsFromServer().then(function (data) {
        var rootnode = [{ name: "Dimensions", items: data.data }];
        options.success(rootnode);
      });
    },
    loadOnDemand: false                
  },
  schema: {
    model: { children: "items" }
  }
});
```